# Receiving CSRF failed. Request aborted

Tags: django, django-csrf

I followed the advice on the error response page, but it still does not work.  here is my code;

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from forms import *
from models import *
def main_page(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      username = form.cleaned_data['username']
      icecream = form.cleaned_data['icecream']
    output = '''
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          Reading user data
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>
          Your ice cream is: %s
        </h1>
      </body>
    </html>''' %(
      icecream
    )
    return HttpResponse(output)


  else:
     form = UserForm()

    variables = RequestContext(request, { 'form': form})

    return render_to_response( 'icecream.html', variables, context_instance=RequestContext       (request))
```

icecream.html (template)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting user input</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h1>Getting user input</h1>
    <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}    
       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from forms.views import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', main_page),
```

settings.py (pertinent section)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',    
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

I am in learning mode so this is just an internal site and I am accessing it using localhost.  I have never had this problem before with the other chapters of the book I am learning from.  This is the first time I am working with forms and posting.  I have looked at a number of answered questions on this site, but nothing seems to help.  All help is appreciated.

Comment: Not quite sure if thats the problem , but why do you allocate two RequestContexts ? Notice that you have one as variables and one you pass directly to context_instance. You dont need to pass the variables inside a request context.

Comment: Make sure you restart whatever server is running. If it's `runserver` CTRL+C it and re-run the command.

Comment: It originally just had this:   return render_to_response( 'icecream.html', variables).  I added the context_instance based on some code I saw earlier.  I'll remove it and see if it helps.

Comment: Show what you see in rendered view of you main_page? Does you have csrf_token token inside?